# Cast to ObjectId failed for value even after Converted to ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Following code **pulling employee from employee Array** in Vendor collection

```
await new VendorManager()
                .update(
                    { employee: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) },
                    { $pull: { employee: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } }
                );
```

String converted into `**mongoose.Types.ObjectId**` but still getting error

```
error: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ employee: 5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a }" at path "_id" for model "Vendor""
```

I have tested before update function

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)
```

It return `true` as well.

> Vendor Schema

```
name: {
    type: String
},
employee: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Employee'
}],
created_by: {
    type: String
},
updated_by: {
    type: String
},
```

Comment: What's your schema please?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT updated Schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the error message, it seems like the first argument to your update function should be an ObjectId and not data shaped like:

```
{ employee:ObjectId }
```

Hence the super helpful error that comes when you try to convert the above object to an ObjectId:

```
error: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ employee: 5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a }" at path "_id" for model "Vendor""
```